# Forward a public zone inside a view from a private BIND

Tags: bind

I have a private BIND server with three views in order to match DNS clients according to their source IP address. One of these views is just to forward the queries for "teamviewer.com" to another recursive BIND servers (which talks to 8.8.8.8) in order to resolve the given hostname because certains desktops must access to this public domain to download Teamviewer client software.

But the queries to *.teamviewer.com fail.

Here is all my BIND configuration:

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf:**

```
server 172.17.8.9 {
   keys {
      dns;
   };
};

controls {
   inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndc-key; };
};

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
//include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
//include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options:**

```
options {
   directory "/var/cache/bind";
   also-notify { 172.17.8.9; };
   dnssec-validation auto;
   dnssec-enable yes;
   auth-nxdomain no;   
   allow-query { any;};
   recursion no;
   version "none";
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local:**

```
acl internet { 10.0.0.0/24; };
acl lan1 { 192.168.0.0/24; };
acl lan2 { 192.168.1.0/24; };

view "internet" {
   match-clients { internet; key "dns"; };

   zone "teamviewer.com" {
      type forward;
      forward only;
      forwarders { 172.18.1.1; };
   };
};

view "internal-1" {
   match-clients { lan1; key "dns"; };

   zone "mycompany-1.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/mycompany-1.com.db";
      allow-transfer { key "dns"; };
   };

view "internal-2" {
   match-clients { lan2; key "dns"; };

   zone "mycompany-2.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/mycompany-2.com.db";
      allow-transfer { key "dns";};
   };
```

This BIND forward the "teamviewer.com" queries to 172.18.1.1 which is our recursive DNS with 8.8.8.8 as its forwarder.

Dig query with `recursion no` in named.conf.options using the IP address of the BIND DNS I'm implementing:

```
$ dig www.teamviewer.com @172.17.8.8 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4 <<>> www.teamviewer.com @172.17.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 62070
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.teamviewer.com.            IN      A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 172.17.8.8#53(172.17.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 12 12:45:07 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Please can you help me to resolve just "teaviewer.com" domain?

Thanks a lot again, regards.

Comment: Please update your question and share the entire configuration of your three views. Include the `dig` command and its output verbatim in the question. This "another recursive BIND server", is that a server you maintain? If so, what is its configuration? If not, who owns it?

Comment: Please **update your question** with this information. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: So who is doing the `dig` in your last code snippet (its IP address)? Since you are using `@172.17.8.8` I assume it's a machine in your local LAN? Then the machine should match one of the internal views, no? Also, perhaps a copy/paste error on your part, but your are missing two `};` statements in your configuration.